# Select duplicates from a single row?

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Here I have a table called CoreTracks:

```
+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| TrackId |       URI       | ArtistID |  Title   | FileSize | BitRate |
+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|  1      | /home/music/... |   234    | atune    |  8958223 |   192   |
|  2      | /home/music/... |   427    | goodsong |  6954373 |   192   |
|  3      | /home/music/... |   427    | goodsong |  4695698 |   128   |
|  4      | /home/music/... |   427    | goodsong |  5839962 |   160   |
|  5      | /home/music/... |   427    | goodsong |  4695698 |   128   |
|  6      | /home/music/... |   522    | another  |  3458859 |   128   |
+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

What I want retrieved is this:

```
+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| TrackId |       URI       | ArtistID |  Title   | FileSize | BitRate |
+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|  3      | /home/music/... |   427    | goodsong |  4695698 |   128   |
|  4      | /home/music/... |   427    | goodsong |  5839962 |   160   |
|  5      | /home/music/... |   427    | goodsong |  4695698 |   128   |
+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

I am trying to remove duplicates based on having the same title, same artist id, and a different track id while not returning the entry with the highest bitrate and the highest filesize.

What I have so far is this:

```
SELECT * FROM CoreTracks 
WHERE Title = Title AND ArtistID = ArtistID 
AND BitRate != (SELECT MAX(BitRate) FROM CoreTracks WHERE Title = Title AND ArtistID = ArtistID) 
AND FileSize != (SELECT MAX(FileSize) FROM CoreTracks WHERE Title = Title AND ArtistID = ArtistID);
```

Which returns every track.  What am I missing to make this query work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would get the inverse (ie skip the duplicates):

```
SELECT c1.*
  FROM CoreTracks c1
      ,(SELECT Title, ArtistID, MAX(FileSize) AS maxFileSize, MAX(BitRate) maxBitRate
          FROM CoreTracks
          GROUP BY Title, ArtistID) c2
  WHERE c1.Title = c2.Title
    AND c1.ArtistID = c2.ArtistID
    AND (c1.FileSize = c2.maxFileSize OR c1.BitRate = c2.maxBitRate)
```

And the duplicates:

```
SELECT c1.*
  FROM CoreTracks c1
      ,(SELECT Title, ArtistID, MAX(FileSize) AS maxFileSize, MAX(BitRate) maxBitRate
          FROM CoreTracks
          GROUP BY Title, ArtistID) c2
  WHERE c1.Title = c2.Title
    AND c1.ArtistID = c2.ArtistID
    AND (c1.FileSize != c2.maxFileSize AND c1.BitRate != c2.maxBitRate)
```

Comment: That's incredible.  Thank you much!

Comment: instead of selecting the duplicate results, how might I go about deleting them?

Comment: @BrandonMinton You could do a "DELETE FROM CoreTracks WHERE TrackId IN (SELECT c1.TrackId FROM ...)

Comment: That works so well and it's fast!  @Glenn You have made learning fun.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Select max(trackId) from  group by Title, ArtistID sort by BitRate asc - then wrap that in another select by the trackId?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.* FROM CoreTracks A, CoreTracks B 
WHERE A.Title = B.Title AND A.ArtistID = B.ArtistID AND A.trackId != B.trackId
HAVING A.BitRate != MAX(A.BitRate) AND A.FileSize != MAX(A.FileSize);
```

Not yet tested but should work.

Comment: This is looking good.  I am however using sqlite (I'm new to it) and it is returning an error: "SQL error: misuse of aggregate function max()".

Comment: Also if you want to delete permanently, you can replace SELECT with DELETE.

Comment: This error is returned: "Error: a GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING".  So I put "GROUP BY A.URI" in front of the HAVING clause and no data was returned.

Comment: I test this on mysql and it works. maybe sql light is different in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Try self join instead of normal query.
I didnot tried it.