# Select duplicates from a single row with criteria from two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables:

```
+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| TrackId |       URI       | ArtistID |  Title   | AlbumID  | BitRate |
+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|  1      | /home/music/... |   234    | atune    |  8958223 |   192   |
|  2      | /music/uri1/... |   427    | goodsong |  222     |   192   |
|  3      | /music/uri2/... |   427    | goodsong |  222     |   128   |
|  4      | /music/uri3/... |   427    | goodsong |  222     |   160   |
|  5      | /home/music/... |   427    | goodsong |  333     |   128   |
|  6      | /home/music/... |   522    | another  |  3458859 |   128   |
+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

and

```
+----------+------------+
| AlbumID  | AlbumTitle |
+----------+------------+
|  8958223 |   titleA   |
|  222     |   titleB   |
|  333     |   titleC   |
|  3458859 |   titleD   |
+----------+------------+
```

Simply put, what I want is this:

```
+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+---------+
| TrackId |       URI       | ArtistID |  Title   | AlbumId  | AlbumTitle | BitRate |
+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+---------+
|  3      | /music/uri2/... |   427    | goodsong |  222     |   titleB   |   128   |
|  4      | /music/uri3/... |   427    | goodsong |  222     |   titleB   |   160   |
+---------+-----------------+----------+----------+----------+------------+---------+
```

This is an attempt to remove duplicates that have the:

- same title
- same artist id
- different track id
- the non-highest bitrate duplicates
- same album name from the album table

while not returning the entry with the highest bitrate duplicate

I've asked a very similar question here: [Select duplicates from a single row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881855/select-duplicates-from-a-single-row)

The solution to that was:

```
SELECT c1.*
  FROM CoreTracks c1
      ,(SELECT Title, ArtistID, MAX(FileSize) AS maxFileSize, MAX(BitRate) maxBitRate
          FROM CoreTracks
          GROUP BY Title, ArtistID) c2
  WHERE c1.Title = c2.Title
    AND c1.ArtistID = c2.ArtistID
    AND (c1.FileSize != c2.maxFileSize AND c1.BitRate != c2.maxBitRate)
```

...but I cannot seem to wrap my head around dealing with another table this time around.

Comment: But the bit-rates are different!

Comment: MySQL and SQLite are different databases - which one is correct?  Databases share functionality, but it's not 100% (or there wouldn't be a need to distinguish).

Comment: I'm using SQLite3.  I'm looking for a general SQL solution but if a particular solution works only in SQLite for some reason, that would still solve this I suppose.

Comment: And where are you use your second table? Can you explain your problem a bit more detailed.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan a very astute point.  I've corrected my question to demonstrate the need for the second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM CoreTracks c1
LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT Title, ArtistID, AlbumID, MAX(BitRate) maxBitRate
      FROM CoreTracks
      GROUP BY Title, ArtistID, AlbumID) c2
    ON c1.Title = c2.Title
    AND c1.ArtistID = c2.ArtistID
    AND c1.AlbumID = c2.AlbumID
    AND c1.BitRate = c2.maxBitRate
WHERE c2.Title IS NULL
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb5f8/6).

--EDIT

To add the Album Title:

```
SELECT c1.*, a.AlbumTitle
FROM CoreTracks c1 
JOIN Albums a on c1.AlbumId = a.AlbumId
LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT c.Title, c.ArtistID, c.AlbumID, MAX(c.BitRate) maxBitRate
      FROM CoreTracks c JOIN Albums A ON c.AlbumId = a.AlbumId
      GROUP BY Title, ArtistID, AlbumID) c2
    ON c1.Title = c2.Title
    AND c1.ArtistID = c2.ArtistID
    AND c1.AlbumID = c2.AlbumID
    AND c1.BitRate = c2.maxBitRate
WHERE c2.Title IS NULL
```

And the updated [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dc4e/8).

Good luck.

Comment: I updated my question as I miserably failed to mention I wanted the album name returned x)  That's why I needed that second table.

Comment: This is excellent.  This helped me break a threshold in comprehension.  I feel like Neo coming out of the Matrix and knowing Kung Fu at long last.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

second table isn't relevant in your use case, since u have the FK reference to AlbumId in the first table

```
select t.*, a.AlbumTitle
from Track t
inner join (
    select max(BitRate) as BitRate, ArtistId, Title, AlbumId
    from Track
    group by ArtistId, Title, AlbumId ) b
  on t.ArtistId = b.ArtistId and t.Title = b.Title and t.AlbumId = b.AlbumId and t.BitRate < b.BitRate
inner join Album a
      on t.AlbumId = a.AlbumId
```

Comment: Ah this is a good point.  It's my mistake that I failed to express that I also wanted the album name returned.

Comment: Thank you pjacko for your response!  I gave it a try and it's yet another excellent way of getting this to work.  Much appreciated.